# Event Trigger In Application Resource Breaks Designer

Tags: wpf, eventtrigger, app.xaml

I added the following to a style I have defined in the Application.Resources:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <SoundPlayerAction Source="..\Resources\ButtonPress1.wav" />
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

It works wonderfully at run-time, however, it breaks the designer. What am I missing?

[Designer Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPICJ.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

He cannot find the source `..\Resources\ButtonPress1.wav`

Comment: Correct. Am I meant to add a reference of some sort to the page itself?